# Wrapping a line of preprocessor C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

How to wrap a line of preprocessor directive and ignore extra space?

Test Code:

```
    #error Line0\
    Line 1
```

Result:

```
short_test.cpp(1): error: #error directive: Line0    Line 1
      #error Line0\
       ^
```

While I want to keep the indent pattern in the test code, I don't want the spacing between line0 and line1 in the result.

Is that possible?

Result that I want:

```
short_test.cpp(1): error: #error directive: Line0Line 1
no space between Line0 and Line1
```

Test Code that I want

```
    #error Line0\
    (extra stuff?) Line 1  <-- keep the indent, ok to insert some extra stuff.
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Could you provide more details about what you _actually_ want to achieve, to avoid the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: the result i want is what i want. I just want to make a long line easier to read with line breaking and indentation. I could put everything in a single line.

Comment: But I doubt you literally want to print `Line0Line 1`... that would be a rather silly error message. Can't you just break the line in a place where you actually want a space?

Comment: I guess this depends on your compiler. Both GCC and clang print both lines of `#error` when trying to compile your code example.

Comment: I see. i was using intel's icc.

Comment: What "extra stuff"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, sorry.

The preprocessor will take precisely what you give it, including any indentation.

Comment: Down with the preprocessor! Revolt! Revolt!